# How to get the pool name from coinbase transaction?

Tags: address, mining-pools, api

Is it possible to retrieve the name of the pool that mined a block looking at the address in the coinbase transaction?

For example, the address in the coinbase transaction of block `00000000000000000002dce191b529017edae3c76d91ab21f757d156daebf43f` is: `1KFHE7w8BhaENAswwryaoccDb6qcT6DbYY`.
From Blockchain Explorer, that block has been mined by F2pool.
Is there a way to associate F2pool with `1KFHE7w8BhaENAswwryaoccDb6qcT6DbYY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although is may be possible to associate addresses that appear in coinbase transactions with mining pools, this relationship can be quickly broken - because they can easily change this address - and that's not how tipically mining pools are identified.

Mining pools/miners that want to identify themselves do so in the `scriptsig` of the coinbase. In your example, the scriptSig is:

`03404a092cfabe6d6d5995dc2134639c494208abda86747b0f77fe5b92e9456a85974f452f51a3da0910000000f09f909f00144d696e6564206279206365616d6b7978696c6f6f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005001f450000`.

If you [decode](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html) this hexadecimal number to `ascii`, you get:
`@J ,ú¾mmYÜ!4cIB«Út{wþ[éEjOE/Q£Ú    ðMined by ceamkyxilooE`

You can see that it contains the string `Mined by ceamkyxiloo`, which is what identifies F2pool. Most of the decoded text is unintelligible because this field (expect the first ~4 bytes) are used to create entropy during mining - what is called "extra nonce".

Most block explorers keep a mapping of these signatures to miners/mining pools. [Here is an (outdated) mapping](https://gist.github.com/denpamusic/e90929485be3282ce0aebd4f2fd1f709).

Comment: Keep in mind: anyone can add `Mined by ceamkyxiloo` (or similar) to the scriptsig of a coinbase output, so it isn't a foolproof method of determining the pool that mined a block.

Comment: They can and do have false self attribution. I know because I was responsible for at least one.

Comment: Why should someone add "Mined by ceamkyxiloo" even if the block was not mined by F2pool?
Also, there is a reason why a pool should keep on changing its address?

Comment: @Rick its impossible to answer *"why would someone do this?"*, but the point is that they can, and have. Mining is designed to be something that can be done anonymously, for hopefully obvious reasons.

Comment: I did it because I thought it was hilarious that people keep trying to “measure decentralization” by looking at a self reported value. Nobody ever noticed, not even the pool it was falsely attributed to.